# Function naming with forward slash?

Tags: symbols

I see this elisp code ([Bernt Hansen)](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html):

```
(defun bh/hide-other ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (org-back-to-heading 'invisible-ok)
    (hide-other)
    (org-cycle)
    (org-cycle)
    (org-cycle)))
```

and I wonder if the `bh/hide-other` name with the forward slash means something special. I'm guessing not. But I need clarification that this isn't some module or namespace rocket science.

Comment: It is common for people to user their own name initials when writing a custom function -- e.g., `bh/`.  Many people dislike forward slash in functions and variables and prefer a dash instead.  The forward slash in the function name does **not** mean anything special -- it could be anything -- e.g., a dash, a forward slash, the letter z, the letter a, etc.  `M-x describe-function RET hide-other RET` -- "*This function is obsolete since 25.1; use `outline-hide-other` instead.  Hide everything except current body and parent and top-level headings.*"

Comment: `/` is a symbol-constituent character in Emacs-Lisp mode. That is, it is an ordinary character for symbol names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no name space in Emacs lisp, so people use various prefixes to avoid name clash.  Section D.1 of [Emacs lisp reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Coding-Conventions.html#Coding-Conventions) recommends using a short prefix followed by one or two hyphen(s):

> • You should choose a short word to distinguish your program from
>       other Lisp programs.  The names of all global symbols in your
>       program, that is the names of variables, constants, and functions,
>       should begin with that chosen prefix.  Separate the prefix from the
>       rest of the name with a hyphen, ‘-’.  This practice helps avoid
>       name conflicts, since all global variables in Emacs Lisp share the
>       same name space, and all functions share another name space(1).
>       Use two hyphens to separate prefix and name if the symbol is not
>       meant to be used by other packages.

See [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/why-does-elisp-not-have-namespaces?s=1|0.8512) about why elisp does not have namespaces.