# How create custom function access only from ONE el file?

Tags: scope

Emacs 26.1
In my file `custom_functions.el`

```
(defun increment-number-by-one-at-point()
  (interactive)
  (increment-number-at-point-private 1))

;; Increment number at point
(defun increment-number-at-point(number)
  (interactive (list (read-number "Input increment number: " 1)))
  (increment-number-at-point-private number))

(defun increment-number-at-point-private(number)
  (skip-chars-backward "0-9")
  (or (looking-at "[0-9]+")
      (error "No number at point"))
  (replace-match (number-to-string (+ number (string-to-number (match-string 0))))))
```

The problem is that `increment-number-at-point-private` is has access in the any place in Emacs List files. But I need that function `increment-number-at-point-private` must have access only in file `custom_functions.el`

Comment: The question as posed is unclear, IMO. But at least @zck seems to have understood what was asked. Perhaps someone could edit the question a bit, to make it more clear?

Comment: I need custom function with private scope

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39550578

Answer (score 2):

If you call `defun`, it creates the function with a global scope. Emacs has no namespaces. There's some previous discussion [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/why-does-elisp-not-have-namespaces), but I won't go into it here.

So what can we do to make a function that does not get bound to a name? We could use `lambda` to create an anonymous function, bind it locally with `let`, and use it the function inside that body. We can use this function inside a named ("public") function:

```
(let ((my-private-function (lambda () (interactive) "Returned privately!")))
  (defun my-public-function ()
    (interactive)
    (replace-regexp-in-string "private" "public" (funcall my-private-function))))

(my-public-function) => "Returned publicly!"
```

This works fine, but we can use some functionality built into Emacs to make `my-private-function` callable by name *inside* the body, but not callable by name outside it.

```
(require 'cl-macs)

(cl-labels ((my-private-function () (interactive) "Returned privately!"))
  (defun my-public-function ()
    (interactive)
    (replace-regexp-in-string "private" "public" (my-private-function))))

(my-public-function) => "Returned publicly!"
```